# Get max value and index of max value from last item in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list of nested lists:

`scoring_matrix = [[1, 2, 7], [3, 5, 2], [2, 2, 7]]`

I am trying to get the max value from all last items in the nested lists, together with the index/indices of the nested list(s) with that max value. All nested lists are of equal length.

In this example:

```
item     output (value, index)
2        [7, [0, 2]]
```

I also needed to get the highest value and index/indices for the last nested list, which I worked out:

```
max_last_list = [index for index, item in enumerate(scoring_matrix[-1]) if item == max(scoring_matrix[-1])]
```

I am attempting to rewrite this line to make it work on my problem, but I can't find out how to do it.

**The solution cannot make use of non-built in modules**

Comment: hint: you need to be iterating over the `scoring_matrix`, not just the last element of it.

Comment: Max per sublist of max overall ?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh of course, that line has a different purpose as I state in my post

Comment: @azro max of all of the last items in all nested lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my first answer, and other answers below :

1. Compute the end's max and find it in the sublists

   ```
   # Find the max of the ends value
   max_end = max(map(lambda x: x[-1], scoring_matrix))
   # Find the sublist whe the last if the overall max
   indexes = [index for index, item in enumerate(scoring_matrix) if item[-1] == max_end]
   # Group result
   result = [max_end, indexes]

   print(result)
   ```
2. Keep the ends together and work on them

   ```
   # Put all ends value in a list
   ends = list(zip(*scoring_matrix))[2]
   # Iterate over the ends to find the overall max
   indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(ends) if v == max(ends)]
   # Group result
   result = [max(ends), indexes]

   print(result)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the below code:

```
l = list(zip(*scoring_matrix))[2]
print([max(l), [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v == max(l)]])
```

Output:

```
[7, [0, 2]]
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it will print `[7, [0, 2]]` when the last nested list is `[2, 2, 6]`. In that case, the output should read `7, [0]]`

Comment: Don't really understant, because you manually write the  `2` value, which should be computed

Comment: @TimStack Isn't the last 2 for the index  of the sublist the maximum number is in?

Comment: No, in my example the index output is `[0, 2]` as the max value resides in those two nested lists :)

Comment: Yes, you got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @U10-Forward's answer,

```
l = list(zip(*scoring_matrix))[2]
print([max(l), [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v == max(l)]])
```

Comment: Oh. The level of co-incidence though. @U10-Forward. It's okay. Now everyone's doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this :

```
maxi = max(sum(scoring_matrix,[]))
res = [maxi,[n for n,i in enumerate(scoring_matrix) if maxi in i]]
```

Output:

```
[7, [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, get the max, then create the list of indices:

```
scoring_matrix = [[1, 2, 7], [3, 5, 2], [2, 2, 7]]

m = max(sublist[2] for sublist in scoring_matrix)
out = [m, [i for i, sub in enumerate(scoring_matrix) if sub[2] == m]]

print(out)
#[7, [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your solution readable. Instead of a clever one-liner, more code with clear variable names is often easier to comprehend.

I would first calculate the maximum and in a second step find the indices for that maximum.

```
scoring_max = max(l[-1] for l in scoring_matrix)
indices = [i for i, sublist in enumerate(scoring_matrix) if sublist[-1] == scoring_max]
return [scoring_max, indices]
```

The solution to your second problem is very similar.

```
last_sublist = scoring_matrix[-1]
list_max = max(last_sublist)
indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(last_sublist) if val == list_max]
```